# C#, сохранение массива как DataGridViewRow?

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне нужно к строке прикрепить не одно значение а список данных. Как это сделать?

Comment: Если вам нужно конкатенировать список данных в строку, то сначала приведите все значения списка данных к строке, а потом используйте `string.Join(s, x) //s - сепаратор, x - массив`.

Comment: Вы хотите массив, в котором бы, например `users[0]` можно было бы получить `user[0].name`, `users[0].lastName` и тд, или я не понял вопроса?

Comment: Вообще ваш вопрос у меня трактуется двойным образом, 1 - вы хотите положить массив данных в строку, 2 - вы хотите в одну строку положить несколько массивов данных, поэтому, очень прошу, уточните вопрос.